# GIMP - shortcut / hotkey for OK button?

Tags: gimp

I use Linux, maybe in Windows dialogs are different, but on Linux e.g. when color is edited if I press `Esc` key changes are reverted back, I want to choose `Ok` w/out using the mouse. I was not able to find if / how to do that, looking at what I've found via web search https://www.gimpusers.com/gimp/hotkeys and https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-concepts-shortcuts.html - opening `preferences`.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. As far as I'm aware there isn't a shortcut for that. You could Tab through the dialog to obtain focus on the OK button, and hit Enter, but that's not very efficient. If you want to quickly apply a filter/adjustment previously applied, then Ctrl+F will repeat the last one.

Comment: The [Enter] key acts as OK in most dialogs, AFAIK.

Comment: @xenoid, checking and looks like "change foreground color" is one of a few where it is not. I actually found out I can edit colors in dockable dialog, so even that minor inconvenience is remedied. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I can accept that. Or better delete the question?